# My WM_KEYDOWN does not work when my MultiLineEdit control is in focus

Tags: api, assembly

i've a window created with my registered class named CLS1

```
invoke CreateWindow,addr CLS1,addr title,WS_OVERLAPPED,
10,10,300,300,NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL
mov hwnd,ax
```

i have a mle on my window like this:

```
invoke CreateWindow,addr clsed,NULL,WS_CHILD or WS_VISIBLE or ES_MULTILINE 
or ES_AUTOVSCROLL or WS_BORDER or WS_TABSTOP,10,10,280,250,hwnd,123,hInstance,NULL
```

and my message loop:

```
.while TRUE
  invoke GetMessage,addr msg,NULL,0,0
  .break .if (ax == 0)
  invoke IsDialogMessage, hwnd,addr msg
  .if (!ax)
     invoke TranslateMessage,addr msg
     invoke DispatchMessage,addr msg
  .endif
 .endw
```

In my WndProc I want (for test) that a WM_KEYDOWN message works and show a Message Box when I press the letter 'A'. So, I've tried this:

```
.if (message == WM_KEYDOWN)
   .if (wParam == 41h)        ;41h = A or a
      invoke MessageBox,NULL,addr keypress,addr title,48
   .endif
```

But it just don't work!

If someone have any solution... please help me.

Sorry my english... i'm not american (lol)

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing for 16-bit windows? If not, checking 16-bit return values and using 16-bit handles is no good:

```
mov hwnd,ax
.break .if (ax == 0)
.if (!ax)
```

use **eax** and things will probably go better.

Comment: maybe... but i'm writing on 16-bits windows... i need to use ax and dx?

Comment: Hm, OK. Then I'm afraid I can't help you.